# Calling a Function Every time I call a Function in a Certain Class

Tags: c#, function, class

The title isn't elegant, and that is partially why I have difficulty researching this on my own.

For example:

```
public class Class1 
{
    CallMeAgain(x)
    {
        if (x < 0)
        {
            //raise exception
        }
    }

    funct1(x)
    {
        CallMeAgain(x);
        //do something
    }

    funct2(x)
    {
        CallMeAgain(x);
        //do something else
    }
}
```

And I have a whole slew of functions like this. I want to be able to call `CallMeAgain` once every time I access a function in `Class1` without typing it for every function.

Edit: In my situation, I have a class that does calculations on special relativity, and I need to make sure that the argument that all the functions take (which is velocity) is less than `c`, or 299,792,458 m/s, otherwise the calculations wouldn't make sense. So in my situation, `CallMeAgain` is a function that checks to see whether or not the velocity is less than `c`.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/tp2VWB0H

Comment: C# doesn't provide any mechanism to call a method every time any other method is called. Perhaps it would be helpful to talk a little bit about why you want this and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Google for "AOP" (aspect oriented programming) and "dynamic proxy"